# How to disable selection or grey out the for particular value in List of value items of drop down list (<ng-selectize> or <options> ) in anguarl 7

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular7

I have scenario where i need to populate list of values for a dropdown list in angular 7 app. But i should grey out the particular value from that list based on condition or flag.

**Eg: I am populating alphabets in UI with drop down list (a to z letters)-> among them i need to disable letter "N" when user try to select that .**

Can any one suggest me how we can do in angular 7

Answer (score 0):

```
<ng-option [value]="item.id" [disabled]="item.disabled" *ngFor="let item of items">
                <img src="./assets/{{item.image}}" width="20px" height="20px"/>
                {{item.name}}
            </ng-option>
```

Used this Code

Answer (score 0):

It could be done by binding a dynamic value to `[disabled]` property.

Component:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  colors =  [
    {value: "Dark Green"},
    {value: "Red"},
    {value: "Dark Grey"},
    {value: "Beige"},
  ];

  fruits =  [
    {value: "Apple", disabled: false},
    {value: "Passion fruit", disabled: true},
    {value: "Dragon fruit", disabled: true},
    {value: "Orange", disabled: false},
  ];

  public ifColorDark(color: string): boolean {
    return color.indexOf('Dark' || 'dark') !== -1;
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<select type="number" [(ngModel)]="selectedItem">
  <option [disabled]="ifColorDark(color.value)" *ngFor="let color of colors" [ngValue]="color.value">{{ color.value }}</option>
</select>

<select type="number" [(ngModel)]="selectedItem">
  <option [disabled]="fruit.disabled" *ngFor="let fruit of fruits" [ngValue]="fruit.value">{{ fruit.value }}</option>
</select>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xft7dz)